# Swift make percentage of width programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, user-interface, uibutton

I am programmatically creating multiple buttons in Swift for a UITableViewCell, and would like to set their widths to be a certain percentage width of the UITableViewCell so that they use up all of the space. Right now I am creating the buttons in a for loop (I want to be able to create a variable amount of buttons) and am using

```
button.buttonWidth = self.contentView.frame.width / numberOfButtons
```

where button is a UIButton and self is a UITableViewCell and numberOfButtons is obviously the number of buttons. I have also tried:

```
button.buttonWidth = self.frame.size.width / numberOfButtons
```

and every combination of using/not using .size and using/not using contentView. These don't seem to work, however, as the buttons are too big. Anyone know how to accomplish this?

NOTE: I CAN'T use Autolayout in the storyboard, as I'm creating a variable number of buttons.

Comment: your reason for not being able to use auto-layout is invalid, you absolutely can use it, what you can't do is specify the constraints in a storyboard or xib...

Comment: You're right--that's what I meant, is that I can't use the storyboard. I'm unaware of how to programmatically use auto-layout, though, so if some can answer using autolayout programmatically, I'll be happy. What I don't want is someone showing me how to use autolayout with the storyboard, which is what everything I've seen up to this point has been. I'll edit the question

Comment: Autolayout Programatically: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html .  Also you could do this with a horizontal `UIStackView` set to `Fill Equally` and then pin the edges of the `UIStackView` to the edges of the `UITableViewCell`. This is one of the many things a `UIStackView` does out-of-the-box.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe because you're doing this before the cell layouts its subviews and it's size is the same as size set in Any-Any size class 600 * 600.

Try doing adding your buttons in `layoutSubviews` method, like this:

```
override func layoutSubviews() {
    super.layoutSubviews()
    self.layoutIfNeeded()

    // add your buttons here

}
```

Comment: This is exactly what is happening. Thank you.

Answer (score 5):

You say:

> NOTE: I CAN'T use Autolayout in the storyboard, as I'm creating a variable number of buttons.

You can't add the variable number of buttons right in Interface Builder, but there's nothing to stop you from using autolayout. The basic autolayout constraints you need to set up are:

- Set buttons to have same width;
- Set buttons to have their leading constraint connected to the previous button's trailing constraint;
- The first button should have its leading constraint connected to the container view; and
- The last button should have its trailing constraint connected to the container, too.

So, for example, in Swift 3, you could do something like:

```
var previousButton: UIButton?
for _ in 0 ..< count {
    let button = ...
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false            
    view.addSubview(button)

    // if no "previous" button, hook leading constraint to its superview;
    // otherwise hook leading constraint and width to previous button

    if previousButton == nil {
        button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previousButton!.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
            button.widthAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previousButton!.widthAnchor, constant: 5)
        ])
    }

    // add vertical constraints

    NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
        button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor, constant: 50),
        view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: button.bottomAnchor, constant: 5)
    ])

    previousButton = button
}

// make sure to hook last button's trailing anchor to superview, too

view.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: previousButton!.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).isActive = true
```

Or, in Swift 2:

```
var previousButton: UIButton?
for _ in 0 ..< buttonCount {
    let button = ...
    button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false            
    view.addSubview(button)

    // if no "previous" button, hook leading constraint to its superview;
    // otherwise hook leading constraint and width to previous button

    if previousButton == nil {
        button.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.leadingAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
    } else {
        NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
            button.leadingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(previousButton!.trailingAnchor, constant: 5),
            button.widthAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(previousButton!.widthAnchor, constant: 5)
        ])
    }

    // add vertical constraints

    NSLayoutConstraint.activateConstraints([
        button.topAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(view.topAnchor, constant: 5),
        view.bottomAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(button.bottomAnchor, constant: 5)
    ])

    previousButton = button
}

// make sure to hook last button's trailing anchor to superview, too

view.trailingAnchor.constraintEqualToAnchor(previousButton!.trailingAnchor, constant: 5).active = true
```

And, instead of fixed spacing between the buttons, you also could use `UILayoutGuide`, too (making the guides the same size as each other but a percent of the width of the buttons, achieving a more natural spacing regardless of the width of the superview).

You also can use `UIStackView`, which is another great way to get controls evenly spaced in a view.

Bottom line, there are many ways to achieve this using autolayout.

Answer (score 1):

Hi there is multiple ways of solving your problem:

1. Using Autolayout, you can using Autolayout in code and in StoryBoard ;-). Bear with me, I didn't check the code of Autolayout but the logic is here…

   ```
   let button1: UIButton!, button2: UIButton!, button3: UIButton!

   convenience init() {
   self.init(frame:CGRectZero)

   contentView.addSubview(button1)
   contentView.addSubview(button2)
   contentView.addSubview(button3)

   button1.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   button2.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
   button3.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

   addConstraint(
       item: button1,
       attribute: .Left,
       relatedBy: .Equal,
       toItem: self,
       attribute: .Left,
       multiplier: 1,
       constant: 8)
   )

   addConstraint(
   item: button2,
   attribute: .Left,
   relatedBy: .Equal,
   toItem: button1,
   attribute: .Right,
   multiplier: 1,
   constant: 8)
   )

   addConstraint(
   item: button1,
   attribute: .Left,
   relatedBy: .Equal,
   toItem: button2,
   attribute: .Right,
   multiplier: 1,
   constant: 8)
   }
   ```

Source: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/ProgrammaticallyCreatingConstraints.html
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/AutolayoutPG/

2. Using Snapkit

   ```
   let button1: UIButton!, button2: UIButton!, button3: UIButton!

   override init(style: UITableViewCellStyle, reuseIdentifier: String?) {
       super.init(style: style, reuseIdentifier: reuseIdentifier)
       button1 = UIButton()
       button1.setTitle("Button 1", forState: .Normal)
       contentView.addSubview(button1)
       button1.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
           make.bottom.equalTo(contentView.snp_botton)
           make.left.equalTo(contentView.snp_left)
           make.height.equalTo(20)
       }

       button2 = UIButton()
       button2.setTitle("Button 2", forState: .Normal)
       contentView.addSubview(button2)
       button2.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
           make.bottom.equalTo(contentView.snp_botton)
           make.left.equalTo(button2.snp_right)
           make.height.equalTo(20)
       }

       button1 = UIButton()
       button1.setTitle("Button 3", forState: .Normal)
       contentView.addSubview(button2)
       button1.snp_makeConstraints { (make) in
           make.bottom.equalTo(contentView.snp_botton)
           make.left.equalTo(button2.snp_right)
           make.height.equalTo(20)
       }
   }
   ```

Source: http://snapkit.io/docs/

My preferred version is Snapkit because it is less verbose than Autolayout.

Comment: Instead of Snapkit, you could use the iOS 9 constraint syntax which is similarly expressive and concise, but doesn't require third party library.

Comment: This is a great answer. Hossam's answer happens to work best for this specific application I'm building, but this is generally more useful and will be of use to me in future applications. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`UIStackView` is exactly what you need. Check out my tutorial below:

http://www.raizlabs.com/dev/2016/04/uistackview/